# How to Create an Access point with ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless-access-point

Is there a way I can configure my notebook as an access point for the desktop pc, my tablet and phone over an internet connection I'm sharing with my neighbor which only connects from the balcony of my house?

Comment: how did you connected your netbook with your neighbour's pc?

Answer (score 2):

This is the tutorial I am using right now and I am sharing with you. Credit goes to [XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2009381).

- Open your terminal and paste as

  ```
  sudo apt-get install hostapd dnsmasq
  ```
- Then paste these one after one.

  ```
  sudo service hostapd stop
  sudo service dnsmasq stop
  sudo update-rc.d hostapd disable
  sudo update-rc.d dnsmasq disable
  ```
- after that paste as

  sudo gedit /etc/dnsmasq.conf

and paste these lines

```
# Bind to only one interface
bind-interfaces
# Choose interface for binding
interface=wlan0
# Specify range of IP addresses for DHCP leasses
dhcp-range=192.168.150.2,192.168.150.10
```

- Then again

  ```
    sudo gedit /etc/hostapd.conf
  ```

paste this

```
# Define interface
interface=wlan0
# Select driver
driver=nl80211
# Set access point name
ssid=myhotspot
# Set access point harware mode to 802.11g
hw_mode=g
# Set WIFI channel (can be easily changed)
channel=6
# Enable WPA2 only (1 for WPA, 2 for WPA2, 3 for WPA + WPA2)
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=mypassword
```

Now open a text editor and paste

```
#!/bin/bash
# Start
# Configure IP address for WLAN
sudo ifconfig wlan0 192.168.150.1
# Start DHCP/DNS server
sudo service dnsmasq restart
# Enable routing
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
# Enable NAT
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
# Run access point daemon
sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd.conf
# Stop
# Disable NAT
sudo iptables -D POSTROUTING -t nat -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
# Disable routing
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=0
# Disable DHCP/DNS server
sudo service dnsmasq stop
sudo service hostapd stop
```

and save it with any script.sh name and do as

```
chmod +x scriptname.sh
./scriptname.sh
```

so you will have a wifi access point.

Note:
    ssid=myhotspot

set the access point name as you want by editing there.

```
wpa_passphrase=mypassword
```

here you can set your password as you want.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
```

change `ppp0` to the connection from which you will get Internet.

```
sudo iptables -D POSTROUTING -t nat -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Here also same change it.

And we are ready to go.